# Как выполнить умножение подхватывая числа из формы?

Tags: javascript

Использую следующий скрипт для выполнения умножения:

```js
(function($) {
  $(function() {
    var argument = $('input[name="argument"]')
      , result = $('input[name="result"]')
      , multiplier = 4;
    argument.on('input', function() {
      result.val($(this).val() * multiplier);
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" name="argument"/>
<input type="number" name="result"/>
```

Как добавить возможность выбора числа, на которое происходит умножение (multiplier), из input select?

```
<input type="number" name="argument"/>
<input type="number" name="result"/>
<select name="currency">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавлю вариант с чистым JS:

```js
let arg = document.querySelector('input[name="argument"]');
let res = document.querySelector('input[name="result"]');
let cur = document.querySelector('select');
let arr = [arg, cur];

let calc = () => res.value = arg.value * cur.value;
arr.forEach(function(el){
 el.addEventListener('input', calc);
});
calc();
```

```html
<input type="number" name="argument" value="2"/>
<input type="text" name="result"/>
<select name="currency">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2" selected>2</option>
  <option value="3" >3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Всё тоже самое, только вместо статического значения берёте `value` с селекта.

```js
(function($) {
  $(function() {
    var argument = $('input[name="argument"]')
      , result = $('input[name="result"]');
    argument.on('input', function() {
    var multiplier = parseInt($('select[name="currency"]').val(), 10);
      result.val($(this).val() * multiplier);
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" name="argument"/>
<input type="number" name="result"/>
<select name="currency">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

Только добавьте чтоб при смене значения в селекте пересчитывало значение.